# escaping double quote characters with Jenkins docker plugin

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to spin up a container using the Jenkins docker plugin as follows:

```
docker.image('microsoft/mssql-server-linux').run("\"ACCEPT_EULA=Y\" -e \"SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword1\" --name SQLLinuxMaster -d -i -p 15565:1433")
```

my initial thoughts were that \" should work, however when I run a build the command is failing, I look in the Jenkins log and it appears that (what I think should be) the escaped double quotes are not appearing.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how I should be correctly escaping the the double quote characters in the run argument.

Using the conventional docker command line the following spins up the container as desired:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword1" --name SQLLinuxChris -d -i -p 15565:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
docker.image('microsoft/mssql-server-linux').run("-e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword1 --name SQLLinuxMaster -d -i -p 15565:1433")
```

You don't need double quotes. Also you were missing a `-e` at the start earlier, which may have caused the issue

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the job.